# Read-only dependency property in UserControl - how to call SetValue with a ViewModel property?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm defining a read-only dependency property via RegisterReadOnly and have removed the CLR-wrapper for the SetValue (approach outlined here and similar to MSDN article http://dotnetslackers.com/WPF/re-131262_WPF_Read_only_Dependency_Properties.aspx)

Now, I can still call SetValue from within the UserControl's code however, in keeping with the spirit of MVVM, how can I call SetValue on the ViewModel without directly referring to the ViewModel instance in code?

The reason I have a read-onnly dependency property on my UserControl is because I want it to only represent state information, and it should not be permissable to rebind it externally

Comment: You want to change the value of the dependency property FROM the ViewModel? That in and of itself "breaks" the MVVM spirit. Can I ask the reason for choosing to use a dependency property in a scenario that you need to interact with it from the data model?

Comment: If the dependency property is read-only, then you won't be able to set it anyway ... right?

Comment: I want the dependency property to represent pure state information, which is coming from the VM which the user control's XAML uses to draw itself and not let external views / code be able to set it (I want them to bind to it and be notified when the state of the VM changes). Without the dep. property, views or code would have to bind using Path=usercontrolsDataContext.ViewModel property so I thought it made sense to create a read-only dependency property on the UserControl that links to the property on the VM?

Comment: @dbaseman: a dependency property can be registered as read-only but you can still call SetValue() on it, in the class it's defined in - eg look at how IsMouseOver is implemented in WPF

Comment: @blue18hutthutt ok, but shouldn't you be binding a property in your View Model to the User Control's dependency property?  That would be more in line with MVVM -- the model shouldn't be able to access the view directly.